# Select object inside an object in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE work_t AS OBJECT(
company VARCHAR2(50),
salary NUMBER(5)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE person_t AS OBJECT(
personnum NUMBER(5),
personname VARCHAR2(20),
personwork work_t
);
/

CREATE TABLE people OF person_t(
PRIMARY KEY (personnum)
);

INSERT INTO people VALUES(12, 'George', work_t('Google',75500));
```

If I want to print personname:

```
DECLARE
per1 person_t;
BEGIN
SELECT VALUE(e) INTO per1 FROM people e WHERE e.personnum = 12;
dbms_output.put_line(per1.personname);
END;
/
```

Now I want to print the company (and update it in different blocks) but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
dbms_output.put_line(per1.personwork.company);
```

in

```
DECLARE
per1 person_t;
BEGIN
SELECT VALUE(e) INTO per1 FROM people e WHERE e.personnum = 12;
dbms_output.put_line(per1.personname);
dbms_output.put_line(per1.personwork.company);
END;
/
```